# C# XNA Mouse movement through velocity?

Tags: c#, xna, mouse

I am trying to set a Mouse object to work through velocity instead of through an absolute position. (Although it tracks both but, Velocity is the way I want to update it.)

However I ran into a few issues.

First off, when in windowed mode the mouse doesn't act right. Since once it moves off screen the mouse wigs out.  I tried using Mouse.SetPosition every Update() tick to set it to the center of the screen, locking it to the window. However this causes issues as well.

To see the issues in action just compile the .sln here -> https://github.com/redcodefinal/Clixel

Everything is automatic so all you need to do is just compile. ClxG has a ClxMouse object already. (ClxG.Mouse)

Here is the whole Mouse class I am working on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace org.clixel
{
    public class ClxMouse : ClxSprite
    {
        private MouseState _curmouse, _lastmouse;

        private int _scrollwheel;


        public bool LeftDown
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curmouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public bool RightDown
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curmouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public bool MiddleDown
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curmouse.MiddleButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public bool LeftPressed
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curmouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && _lastmouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public bool RightPressed
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curmouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed && _lastmouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Released)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public bool MiddlePressed
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curmouse.MiddleButton == ButtonState.Pressed && _lastmouse.MiddleButton == ButtonState.Released)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public MouseState CurMouse
        {
            get
            {
                return _curmouse;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public MouseState LastMouse
        {
            get
            {
                return _lastmouse;
            }
            set { }
        }

        public ClxMouse()
            : base(ClxAssets.Textures.Cursor)
        {
            _curmouse = Mouse.GetState();
            _lastmouse = _curmouse;
            CollisionBox = new Rectangle(ClxG.Screen.X/2, ClxG.Screen.Y/2, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
            this.Solid = false;
            Mouse.SetPosition(CollisionBox.X, CollisionBox.Y);
        }

        public ClxMouse(Texture2D _texture)
            : base(_texture)
        {
            _curmouse = Mouse.GetState();
            _lastmouse = _curmouse;
            CollisionBox = new Rectangle(ClxG.Screen.Center.X, ClxG.Screen.Center.Y, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            _lastmouse = _curmouse;
            _curmouse = Mouse.GetState();

            Velocity = new Vector2(_curmouse.X - _lastmouse.X, _curmouse.Y - _lastmouse.Y);
            Console.WriteLine(Velocity.ToString());
            base.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

TLDR: How do I lock the mouse to a window without exploding the entire world in the proccess?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if your mouse is out of bounds each frame. If it is, you need to set it to the other side of the window. You will need to create some.kind of margin inside the screen to check for out of bounds cuz its already too late if the mouse is actually out of the screen) So if you have a screen of 800x600 for instance, you could use a margin of 20px (so the mouse needs to stay in a box of 760x560, with an offset of (20,20)) and in a certain frame the mouse position is (400,567) you know it's out of bounds by (0,7) [mouse position - margin]-> if the x and/or y are positive you need to reset the mouse position using those values. So in the example the new mouse position will be (400,27) [27 cuz you have a margin of 20px on every edge] (x stays the same because 400-760 will be smaller then 0). This way you can move the mouse infinite and use mouse position difference of each frame to calculate the velocity.